# How can i rollback in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I gotta question about Oracle Transaction.

```
INSERT INTO HAR_DENEME (ID, NAME, SURNAME)
     VALUES (140, 'tt', 'AA');

UPDATE HAR_DENEME
   SET NAME = 'osman'
 WHERE ID = 500;---> there is no data ID=500;
```

How can I rollback first query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also add a savepoint and rollback to the savepoint

```
begin
  savepoint SP_INSERT;

  INSERT INTO HAR_DENEME (ID,NAME,SURNAME) VALUES(140,'tt','AA'); 

  update HAR_DENEME set NAME='osman' where ID=500;---> there is no data ID=500;
  if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then

    rollback to savepoint SP_INSERT;
  end if;

end;
```

you can check the rowcount of you update. if there is nothing to update you can do a rollback

Comment: if there is a data like ıd=500 then update have to work if not it doesn't how can do this thanks

Comment: Thanks bro it means a lot for me

Comment: Can i ask another question if the query select or insert how can i do that rollback?

Comment: ìf you select a row that does not exists it will throw no_data_found exception. you can use exception handling for that.

Comment: What about wrong insert? thanks for select again and i saw that delete rollback working like update

Comment: what do you mean with wrong insert? how do you know that it is a wrong insert. create for that a new question and describe you problem more clear

Comment: I mean if data is number and i insert string. I found a error invalid number. I understand how to handle rollback thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

If your development tool isn't set for autocommit (and I hope it isn't) then you can execute simple command:

```
rollback;
```

Comment: i want to rollback when data is null or not found

Comment: Still does the insert :(

Comment: update and insert doesn't throw  no_data_found exeption!

Comment: Thank you @hotfix I failed to remember that xD I'll remove the second part of my answer